# Как использовать словари в условиях?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, словари, telebot

Сейчас пишу телеграмм бота на библиотеке pytelegrambotapi.
В этой библиотеке можно ставить условие на сообщение от пользователя, то есть если сообщение пользователя равно ***какое-то слово***, то бот отвечает ***ответ на сообщение***

Так вот, появилась идея сделать конструктор команд. Админ пишет в личные сообщение боту, например ***Слово; Ответ на Слово***, это сообщение я разделяю по словам и заношу в словарь(первые слова до ; будут ключом, все остальные, после ; - значением.

Итак, например админ добавил 5 команд и ответы на них, они хранятся в словаре, как ключ-значение.

Как мне можно в обработчике команд сделать, что если сообщение от пользователя было равно одному из ключей, то бот отвечал ему значением этого ключа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

*qa - вашь словарь где вопросы и ответы;*

```
if message.text in qa: 
     bot.send_message(qa[message.text], send_mess, parse_mode='html')
else:
     bot.send_message('Я вас не понял', send_mess, parse_mode='html')
```